# Add column description to BiqQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

need to add descriptions to each column of a BigQuery table, seems I can do it manually, how to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 7):

As Adam mentioned, you can use the table PATCH method on the API to update the schema columns. The other method is to use bq.

You can first get the schema by doing the following:

1: Get the JSON schema:

```
TABLE=publicdata:samples.shakespeare

bq show --format=prettyjson ${TABLE} > table.txt
```

Then copy the schema from table.txt to schema.txt ... it will look something like:

```
[
  {
    "description": "A single unique word (where whitespace is the delimiter) extracted from a corpus.",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "word",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "The number of times this word appears in this corpus.",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "word_count",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  ....
]
```

2:  Set the description field to whatever you want (if it is not there, add it).

3: Tell BigQuery to update the schema with the added columns. Note that schema.txt must contain the complete schema.

```
 bq update --schema schema.txt -t ${TABLE}
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, I tried this method however I kept getting error: BigQuery error in update operation: Provided Schema does not match Table tableABC, what could be the cause?

Comment: It sounds like there was some other schema difference detected between the one you specified and the one on the table. If it doesn't work, you could describe it in a new question (it is probably too long to describe in a comment).

Comment: sorry for the long comments, it worked when I spared the headers and trailor from the schema file retrieved, thank you.

Comment: For some reason your `bq show` command didn't work for me as is and I needed to add a `--schema` flag: `bq show --schema --format=prettyjson ${TABLE} > table.txt`

Comment: Are there any plans to support this as DDL, e.g. `ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c SET OPTIONS (DESCRIPTION = 'abc')`?

Answer (score 7):

BigQuery now supports ALTER COLUMN SET OPTIONS statement, which can be used to update the description of a column

example:

```
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
ALTER COLUMN price
SET OPTIONS (
  description="Price per unit"
)
```

Documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_column_set_options_statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API to create or update a table, and specify a field desciption (schema.fields[].description) in your schema.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#methods